# Is there any primary source for Mussolini being called "Juliet"?

Tags: italy, mussolini

So, I have heard a rather amusing, but seemingly apocryphal story (as an answer on game show), that Italians called Benito Mussolini "Juliet", due to his liking of speeches given on balconies.

I tried to figure out whether that was indeed the case, and ran into a bit of an evidence problem:

- Couldn't find any evidence Googling in English (either none exists, or my Google-fu sucks)
- Don't speak Italian so can't search in Italian
- Now, Russian, actually gave a bit of a lead.

  Specifically, I found a bunch of places stating this as hearsay, BUT, also, dug up [a single Russian article](https://db.chgk.info/contact/question/taviv10.5/10?destination=/question/taviv10.5/10) (just one), with an actual cited source - specifically, [a Russian translation](http://militera.lib.ru/bio/collier_r/index.html) of a book *"Duce! A biography of Benito Mussolini" by Collier. (New York: Viking. 1971)*.

  Unfortunately, I don't have access to either original NOR searchable Russian translation, to ascertain the validity of the citation. And more importantly, **whether it has a cited primary source**.

Thus, my question...

## Is there any primary source for Mussolini being called "Juliet" by Italians, because of speeches given on balconies?

Comment: The original Collier book is available to borrow on the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/ducebiographyofb0000coll/page/186/mode/2up) (see page 186) but there's no source given for him being called 'Juliet'.

Comment: FWIW, the Italian for "Juliet" is "Giuletta". But my Ecosia-fu didn't provide more sources.

Comment: I'm from italy, and haven't found any source about that; it is also first time I've heard about this kind of nickname.
Don't know if abroad was a common nickname, but not widespread in italy - as far as I know.

Comment: Compton Mackenzie's 1943 _Wind of freedom_ repeats this quip, on p.33: "Juliet the wags of Rome called Mussolini, because he was for ever appearing on balconies." https://archive.org/details/dli.ministry.07169/page/33/mode/2up?q=juliet

Comment: @kimchilover It may also be the original source of the 'quote', seeing that this book (published in London) is telling the allies point of view during the war (i.e Propaganda). Also Chapter 2, page 16: *Mussolini protested the innocence of Fascist Italy’s intentions in the accents of a bawd guaranteeing virginity in a brothel.*.

Comment: @kimchilover An answer, citing Compton Mackenzie's  Wind of freedom (THE HISTORY OF THE INVASION OF GREECE BY THE AXIS POWERS 1940-1941) published 1943 in London as the first found use of this 'quote', would be appropriate.

Comment: @kimchilover In [Compton Mackenzie - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compton_Mackenzie#Background), 'Wind of freedom' is not listed as one of his books. It does meantion that his grandfather Henry Compton, was a well-known Shakespearean actor of the Victorian era and that he worked for the British Intelligence during WWI in Greece.

Comment: @MarkJohnson  Yes it does, item 13 under "History and Biography", with a link to a book review.

Comment: @DVK: Google's snippet view confirms the Russian reference: Richard Collier, *Duce! A Biography of Benito Mussolini.* New York: Viking Press 1971, p. 186: " ... for he had ranted so often now from Palazzo Venezia's balcony that cynical Romans nicknamed him 'Juliet' " No primary source appears to be cited, but snippets cut off at unpredictable places.

Comment: Funny thing: searching for "Mussolini Giulietta" returned that he actually owned an Alfa Romeo Giulietta

Answer (score 39):

The sarcastic comments remarking on Mussolini's predilection for balcony speeches and comparing him to Juliet or Romeo goes back to **1935** or earlier in the English-language press.

The [November 11, **1935** *Dansville (NY) Breeze*](https://fultonhistory.com/Newspaper%2011/Dansville%20NY%20Breeze/Dansville%20NY%20Breeze%201935%20Grayscale/Dansville%20NY%20Breeze%201935%20Grayscale%20-%201077.pdf) contains one article about Mussolini reviewing his Italian army from a balcony, and a "barb" mentioning him in conjunction with Romeo and Juliet's balcony:

> The forthcoming film, "Romeo and Juliet," may have to be produced in America, since Il Duce apparently has a monopoly on all Italian balconies.

In the [September 3, **1937** *Albany (NY) Times Union*](https://fultonhistory.com/Login_18/Albany%20NY%20Times%20Union/Albany%20NY%20Times%20Union%201937/Albany%20NY%20Times%20Union%201937%20-%207495.pdf) Arthur "Bugs" Baer wrote:

> We pointed out some years ago that no European dictator would allow Juliet out on the balcony in the balcony scene. That's because the pigeon ledge is restricted solely for the use of Stalin, Hitler and Mussolini, for the reviewing of troops and the broadgabbing of speeches.

The [July 10, **1938** *Imperial Valley Press*](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn92070146/1938-07-10/ed-1/seq-4/print/image_681x648_from_3733%2C5077_to_5403%2C6668/) from El Centro, California included a filler item (also published in the [July 8, 1938 *Schenectady Gazette*](https://fultonhistory.com/Newspaper%208/Schenectady%20NY%20Gazette/Schenectady%20NY%20Gazette%201938%20Grayscale/Schenectady%20NY%20Gazette%201938%20Grayscale%20-%204001.pdf) under the byline of William Ritt) that read as follows:

> An old-timer is a fellow who can remember when the word "balcony" brought to mind "Romeo and Juliet" and not Benito Mussolini.

The [April 13, **1939** *Western News*](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn82006551/1939-04-13/ed-1/seq-3/print/image_681x665_from_0%2C3506_to_2647%2C6092/) from Libby, Montana contained an announcement of a lecture by [Dr. Robert L. Housman](https://scholarworks.umt.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1035&context=communique), a Russian-born professor who earned the first Ph. D. in journalism in the U.S.:

> Tuesday morning, the high school was pleased to hear an address by Dr. Housman, head of the Department of Journalism at the University of Montana. . . . He described the Fascist replic [sic] of this system ruled over by Mussolini, to whom he said, correspondents refer to "Juliet," because he is always on a balcony.

The [September 27, **1939** *Binghamton (NY) Press*](http://fultonhistory.com/Newspaper4/Binghamton%20NY%20Press%20Grayscale/Binghamton%20NY%20Press%20Grayscale%201939.pdf/Binghamton%20NY%20Press%20Grayscale%201939%20-%206503.pdf) said:

> As a neutral, Muss did maintain the socalled Silence of Cuneo long enough to make European chancellories wonder whether the cat had his tongue. But he stood it just about so long and then broke forth beautifully at a Fascist old home week celebration where he announced that when he had anything important to say he would tell the world from the balcony of the Palazzo Venezia, presumably playing the part of Romeo to Hitler's Juliet.

The [November 14, **1939** *Buffalo (NY) Courier-Express*](https://fultonhistory.com/Newspapers%2021/Buffalo%20NY%20Courier%20Express/Buffalo%20NY%20Courier%20Express%201939/Buffalo%20NY%20Courier%20Express%201939%20-%207601.pdf) contained an article by William L. White with the following exchange:

> "The Old Man is more popular in Italy today than he ever was." 
>  "What about the story that they now call him Juliet, because he is always singing to them from the balcony?" 
>  "Sure they call him Juliet. The Italians are great kidders. They have to kid even the things they love. I could make a book of Italian stories like that on Mussolini I've heard ever since I first came to the country."

The [August 25, **1942** *Detroit (Michigan) Evening Times*](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn88063294/1942-08-25/ed-1/seq-12/print/image_681x648_from_1907%2C2990_to_4986%2C5922/) ran a syndicated King Features piece that included a list of jokes, including this one:

> If Juliet were to play the balcony scene with Mussolini, where would she stand?

By **1942**, Mussolini and his balcony were so entwined that there was even a book titled [*Balcony Empire*](https://archive.org/details/balconyempire0000reyn/page/n5/mode/2up), subtitled "Fascist Italy at War." However, the book does not seem to have any references to Shakespeare's Romeo or Juliet.

Comment: Professors lecturing in Libby on the rise of fascism? Different times ...

Answer (score 14):

The Scottish author [Compton Mackenzie (1883-1972)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compton_Mackenzie) is famous for his comic novels (notably, *Whiskey Galore* in 1947), but, in 1943, published a propaganda work [Wind of Freedom: The history of the invasion of Greece by the Axis powers, 1940–1941](https://archive.org/details/dli.ministry.07169).
On page 33, at the very end of Chapter 2, he wrote

> Once upon a time Cleon the Tanner bawled as loud as this from the Bema, and Athens followed his voice along the road to ruin.
> Juliet the wags of Rome called Mussolini, because he was for ever appearing on balconies. One day, will true Italians fling that greasy bag of wind to the Roman mob surging below: and make of their Juliet a Jezebel.

I have not read this book, and do not know if Mackenzie's comment about the wags of Rome is correct, or even if Mackenzie was in a position to know it was correct, or supposing it true, if the wags in question were   Italians or foreigners.

So *Wind of Freedom* is hardly a reliable primary source for the truth of the "Juliet" story.

But this is an instance of the occurrence  of the  "Juliet" story, and, possibly the first instance.

Comment: A *modern* [Italian source](https://www.inchiostronero.it/se-tornasse-cicerone-ius-murmurandi/) claims the nickname originated among the literary crowd frequenting the [Caffè Aragno](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caff%C3%A8_Aragno) in Rome:
" *Famoso a Roma il caffè Aragno, dove le più velenose lingue dell’intellighentzia nostrana coniavano battute fulminanti, sottovoce, che non le sentisse l’eventuale spia dell’Ovra, travestita da cameriere. Mussolini fu soprannominato Giulietta, perché stava sempre al balcone, e Diego Calcagno gli affibbiò il motto «sbagliando s’impara».* "

Comment: William Shakespeare wrote in english, and balconies have not been prominently used in english architecture, so the connection balcony-Juliet would naturally spring to mind to an english speaker only. As a spaniard, the first idea that comes attached to "balcony" is 'drunk briton dies in Magaluf after falling from a balcony'. We know who Shakespeare was, certainly, but he's not the almost omnipresent figure that is in English-speacking arts, and I guess it's the same for Italy.

Comment: @njuffa Good find.  Unlike my answer and the other answer, your source points to the Juliet comparison being used by Italians.

Comment: @kimchilover The excerpt I quoted from the website originally seems to be from Cesare Marchi, *Siamo tutti latinisti.* Rizzoli, 1986, p. 132. A problem with citing modern Italian works is that they may incorporate material from non-Italian sources, and one cannot tell whether that is the case or not when no specific primary source is cited, as is the case here. BTW and FWIW, the nickname mentioned in the very next sentence made me grin from ear to ear: " *Italo Balbo, governatore della Libia, ebbe il titolo di Sciupone l’Africano e anche Duca di Cleptis Magna.* "

Comment: @Rekesoft I have always been struck that educated Europeans outside Britain have a far better knowledge of the giants of English literature than we have of, say, Molière, Schiller, or Goethe. A "literary crowd" in Roman café society would easily make this connection.

Comment: @MichaelKay Sure, but a "literary crowd" are a bunch of writers around several cups of coffee. Not the general public. I doubt the idea got any traction outside those niche circles.

Comment: @Rekesoft: Ah, but like many of Shakespeare's plays, the plot of *Romeo and Juliet* was lifted from Italian folklore.  Wikipedia [mentions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romeo_and_Juliet#Sources) an Italian story entitled *Giulietta e Romeo*, published by Luigi da Porto in 1531, that contains almost all the elements of the play's plot, specifically including the balcony scene.  So an Italian wouldn't have to be familiar with English drama or other foreign literature to know the story.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_films_based_on_Romeo_and_Juliet shows Italian film adaptations of the play from 1908 and 1912, which probably wouldn't have been commercially viable unless the story was well-known.  I would also guess that, for anyone living in or near Verona (where the play is set), they'd be used to encountering British or American tourists looking for "the balcony".

Comment: @NateEldredge Of course they knew about the story. I doubt the connection "balcony-Juliet" was made. A balcony may be an exotic thing in the UK, it's not so in Italy. There are many ideas that may spring to mind when you think about balconies in a culture that has millions of them. The connection "windmill-don Quixote" is way more unique, and windmills way rarer than balconies, and yet I don't encounter many references to Cervantes when I consume english-speacking media. Despite translations, adaptations and films being made in Hollywood.